# Can only debug main project in solution containing 3

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I've been working on an application for a while now and after passing it in release mode, I found out that the 2 other projects (other than the main application), which are classe libraries, cannot be debugged anymore. Moreover, it's not even taking account of the changes I make to the code in these projects in debug.

When using the **Debug > Windows > Module** I clearly see that for those two module, it cannot load the PDB file, I get the *Cannot find or open the PDB file*. What's strange is that when I take a look in **Symbol Load Informations** it's always looking in the Release folder for the PDB now, even when I change my active configuration to Debug.

So I tried locating my PDB file with the **Load Symbols From > Symbol Path** but they never match, even if I get the one in the Debug folder that's just been rebuilt.

I tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding it multiple times, restarted VS2010, restarted my computer, deleting the *obj\Debug* and *obj\Release* folder to recreate them, deleting the *bin\Debug* and *bin\Folder* to recreate them, no luck.

My PDB get's recreated everytime I build the app, but it never matches with the original PDB (what exactly is the 'original PDB' anyway?).

**EDIT** 
I tried adding a new project with a single class and referencing it in my main App. The symbols are loaded allright, I can Debug it without any problem. If I don't find a solution I'll try recreating those projects from scratch, hoping it'll work...

Comment: Make sure you are referring the assemblies from those project and not from elsewhere

Comment: Like Siriam said, check how you reference the class libraries. In the Reference Manager dialog you can use Solution - Projects or you can use Browse and find the DLL.

Comment: I forgot to talk about it but yeah I removed the references and tried adding them back, in both cases I added those references through the "Projects" tab...

Comment: Okay so I got it working for a while by re-creating my whole project from scratch. But then I changed my configuration again to Release, came back to Debug and the problem's there again. Apart from my main project, the 2 others class libraries can't be debugged. But that's not the only problem, as I said, it doesn't event take the changes I make to those libraries in account. So I'm stucked with the current version and I cannot edit it. I tried recreating the project but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had the problem several times and I ended up adding my side projects directly to my main project on a different namespace for the sake of convenience.

No exactly the best approach to object oriented programming but had no other choices, now it's working fine.